# Sort Dict by value in List of nested Dict

Tags: python, dictionary

This has been driving me nuts for days, I've seen several questions on sorting Dicts by value, but they are simple structures and mine is complex.

My top level Dict Key is a hash, the sub Dict Key is a sequence #, and the sub Dict value is a list. The last value in that is a number, which is what I want to sort the top level Dict by. The size of the Dict can be quite large, but here is a sample:

```
 {'16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf': 
    {1: [0, '16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf', 'data-01', 1132],
     2: [1, '16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf', 'data-02', 1132],
     3: [2, '16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf', 'data-03', 1132]},

 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093':
    {4: [0, 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093', 'data-04', 55296],
     5: [1, 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093', 'data-05', 55296],
     6: [1, 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093', 'data-06', 55296],
     7: [2, 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093', 'data-07', 55296]},
 'a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724':
    {8: [0, 'a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724', 'data-08', 20125],
     9: [1, 'a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724', 'data-09', 20125],
    10: [1, 'a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724', 'data-10', 20125]}}
```

This code will give me the value I'm looking for, but only for the first iteration, then I get **KeyError: 1**

```
for item1 in mydict.items():
    print(item1[1][1][3])

item1[1] returns subkey 1's list
item1[2] returns subkey 2's list
item1[3] returns subkey 3's list
item1[1][1][3] returns subkey 1's "value"
```

I want to be able to sort the dict forward and reverse by that value. I've seen:

```
sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

I can't figure out how to apply that to my problem, generally my attempts end up with KeyError: 1 or IndexError: string out of range.

What am I missing?
How can I reference that value for lamba?
Is that what I need to do?

I'd prefer not to use a solution that includes Pandas. I'm trying to make this fast/efficient since the data can be quite large (currently 10,000 subkeys)

**Edit:**

Output would look the same but sorted by last value in list:

```
 {'16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf': 
    {1: [0, '16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf', 'data-01', 1132],
     2: [1, '16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf', 'data-02', 1132],
     3: [2, '16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf', 'data-03', 1132]},

 'a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724':
    {8: [0, 'a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724', 'data-08', 20125],
     9: [1, 'a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724', 'data-09', 20125],
    10: [1, 'a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724', 'data-10', 20125]},

 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093':
    {4: [0, 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093', 'data-04', 55296],
     5: [1, 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093', 'data-05', 55296],
     6: [1, 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093', 'data-06', 55296],
     7: [2, 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093', 'data-07', 55296]}}
```

Comment: each hash key has same int value in the key values last element ?

Comment: Show us how the output would look like

Comment: You can't sort a *dict*. They are unsorted by definition. Use `collections.OrderedDict`. What's the output you're expecting for this particular example? Also `for key1 in mydict.items():` is misleading.

Comment: Ok, can't sort dict, how can I achieve what I want, recreate a new dict ordered by that value? How?

Comment: @CristiFati - starting with Python 3.7 (or 3.6 if using the CPython implementation) dicts are insertion-order aware.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.5 (default, Dec  5 2018, 20:21:13)  FreeBSD

Comment: @zwer: hm..... good point. I didn't pay attention to such details :)

Comment: @zwer technically pypy has order-preserving dict from Pypy 2.5 (Python 2.7 / 3.2.5)

Comment: Thanks everyone, give me a little time to understand your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, what I understand is that you have `{k1: {k2: [v1, v2, v3, v4]}}`, you want to sort every top-level entry by `v4` which should be the same in every list (so it doesn't matter which we pick). However the the sub-entries (`k2`) are not constant between the top-level entries.

Getting v4 from a sub-entry is easy (`[3]` or `[-1]`) the issue is getting an arbitrary value of the second-level dict. `next(iter(d.values()))` ought do: iterate the sub-values (the lists), and get the first value out of the iterator. Not that this will raise an error if a sub-entry is empty (a top-level key maps to an empty dict).

So `sorted(data.items(), key=lambda e: next(iter(e[1].values()))[-1])` should work:

```py
[('16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf',
  {1: [0, '16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf', 'data-01', 1132],
   2: [1, '16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf', 'data-02', 1132],
   3: [2, '16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf', 'data-03', 1132]}),
 ('a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724',
  {8: [0, 'a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724', 'data-08', 20125],
   9: [1, 'a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724', 'data-09', 20125],
   10: [1, 'a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724', 'data-10', 20125]}),
 ('cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093',
  {4: [0, 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093', 'data-04', 55296],
   5: [1, 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093', 'data-05', 55296],
   6: [1, 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093', 'data-06', 55296],
   7: [2, 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093', 'data-07', 55296]})]
```

Be aware that this will return a list of `(key, value)` tuples, not a dictionary. You'll have to feed it back to `dict` (ideally OrderedDict, possibly the regular `dict` in Python 3.6 or more recent) to keep the order:

```py
{'16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf': 
   {1: [0, '16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf', 'data-01', 1132],
    2: [1, '16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf', 'data-02', 1132],
    3: [2, '16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf', 'data-03', 1132]},
 'a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724': 
   {8: [0, 'a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724', 'data-08', 20125],
    9: [1, 'a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724', 'data-09', 20125],
    10: [1, 'a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724', 'data-10', 20125]},
 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093': {
    4: [0, 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093', 'data-04', 55296],
    5: [1, 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093', 'data-05', 55296],
    6: [1, 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093', 'data-06', 55296],
    7: [2, 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093', 'data-07', 55296]}}
```

Comment: I think you understand what I'm trying to achieve. I like the simplicity of your answer, let me adapt it into my app and see what happens.

Comment: @sdproto - Be aware that with this you will be sorting only considering the first list of each sub-sub dict, you would have to sort the sub-sub dicts first (or nested sorting of `e[1].values()`) if the last value of your lists can differ in the same 'group'.

Comment: Thanks, last value remains constant. I realize I need to restructure my list and reduce the dupe values, but for now its ok.

Comment: @zwer yes I specifically pointed that assumption (all lists have the same v4 by which we sort) in the first paragraph of my answer

Comment: @Masklinn - List looks great, everything looks correct. Sorry took me a bit to implement, great solution. Is this all I need to convert back to dict? newdict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(MyDict.items(), key=lambda e: next(iter(e[1].values()))[-1]))

Comment: @Masklinn, meant to say your solution was brilliant, I knew it was something easy, just couldn't wrap my head around it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ugly (and pretty inefficient) variant. It combines a *dict* comprehension, sorting, and getting the *dict* value corresponding to the 1<sup>st</sup> of the keys (by (the ugly) `d[list(d.keys())[0]]`):

> ```py
> >>> data.keys()
> dict_keys(['16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf', 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093', 'a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724'])
> >>> data_sorted = {k: v for k, v in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][list(x[1].keys())[0]][3])}
> >>> data_sorted.keys()
> dict_keys(['16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf', 'a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724', 'cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093'])
> ```

You've got *KeyError* in `item1[1][1][3]` because ***1*** (**the 2<sup>nd</sup>** one) only exists in the sub-dictionary of `'16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf'`.

Your *dict* contains an awful amount of duplication. It could be trimmed down to something like (also making the sorting expression much simpler):

> ```py
> >>> data = {("16741b673a418af3812f6d43ea3f7daf", 1132): ["data-01", "data-02", "data-03"],
> ...         ("cbef6de99cc2b9739c824db6d0246093", 55296): ["data-04", "data-05", "data-06", "data-07"],
> ...         ("a1e0f7ccdd8d38cb5ae00cdac71b6724", 20125): ["data-08", "data-09", "data-10"]}
> >>>
> >>> {k: v for k, v in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[0][1])}
> ```

Comment: Thank you, I'll have to give that a try, thanks for the explanation. I realize there's a lot of duplication, I was a little embarrassed to post that, but I intend to fix that. I'm just having trouble understanding how to reference the different keys/values at the different levels since they don't really have names. Its getting late for me, so tomorrow.

Comment: There's nothing to be embarrassed for. As I exemplified to get a *dict* value, get its keys, pick one and get its corresponding values. Keys have "names" even if they are not strings (in your inner *dict*s they are *int*s). The inner *dict* values are lists, so the concept of a *key* doesn't make sense there, elements are referenced by index .

Comment: I like your proposed new structure, the only thing is I needed the second key as a sort of cross reference so I could update/remove that specific element. I'll have to give it some more thought, but you've given me a great starting point, thanks.

Comment: Yes it's easy to convert your initial dictionary (the one with *10k* items) into the new format, and work on that one. Also whoever is producing the dictionary should be changed as well to respect the new format from now on.